# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLayer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am using KineticJS, but when I try to remove two components on a layer on stage (a Kinetic.Image instance and a Kinetic.Text instance), I get the uncaught typerror, even when I have put my code in the try catch block.

What is causing the error?

This is the relevant code

```
var arr = myStage.getChildren()[1].get(".sceneComponents");

for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        //arr[i].setVisible(false);   // Setting its visibility to false works absolutely fine
        arr[i].remove();  //Trying to remove like this throws the uncaught error
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        console.log(ex);
    }
}
```

This is the complete error log.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLayer' of undefined kinetic.js:37
Kinetic.Node.getLayer kinetic.js:37
Kinetic.Shape.drawHit kinetic.js:42
Kinetic.Container.drawHit kinetic.js:41
Kinetic.Layer.drawHit kinetic.js:44
Kinetic.Container.drawHit kinetic.js:41
Kinetic.Container.draw kinetic.js:41
tick mainScript.js:221 //This is refering to the myStage.draw() line in my code
```

UPDATE:

When I used this to remove the components-

```
layer.arr[i].remove();
```

I get the following error on the same line

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: Log the arr and see if there are values in there that should not be there.

Comment: @Klaasvaak They are absolutely fine. My suspicions are going towards the way I am using the remove function. In the docs, it does not explain how to use it. Is the way I am using it right?

Comment: You can try removing it from the layer instead using Layer.remove

Comment: @Klaasvaak, no that did not work either. I think that removes the layer itself.

Comment: You are right about that. If you want to remove all children on a layer call Layer.removeChildren(). If you want to remove one item call remove() on that item. the items in arr are placed on a layer?

Comment: @Klaasvaak yes i did that, but when I try to access components within that layer afterwords from the layer, I get the error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined`. This probably means that layer is removed and that is why it is undefined

Comment: @Klaasvaak yes the items in `arr` are placed in a layer. Thanks very much for helping, I really appreciate it. Please help me through this.

Comment: Maybe save the items you use to draw on a layer in some vars so you can access them, this is what I always do. If that does not work report it: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues

Comment: @Klaasvaak Update. Can you spot any obvious problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create, for example a rectangle, you remove it like this:

```
//create stage have a div with id container:
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: 'container',
                width: CANVAS_WIDTH,
                height: CANVAS_HEIGHT
            });

//add layer
var myLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(myLayer);

//add black rectangle to layer
var myRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
x: yourX,
y: yourY,
width: yourWitdh,
height: yourHeight,
fill: 'black'
});
myLayer.add(myRect);

//remove rectangle from layer
myRect.remove();
myLayer.draw()
```

If you want to remove everything in a layer call:

```
myLayer.removeChildren();
```

You can also hide and show a shape:

```
rect.show();
rect.hide();
```

The visisble attribute will be set to true or false. If it's false it will not be drawn. See:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/Shape.js

```
if(drawFunc && this.isVisible()) {
                context.save();
                canvas._applyOpacity(this);
                canvas._applyLineJoin(this);                
                canvas._applyAncestorTransforms(this);
                drawFunc.call(this, canvas);
                context.restore();
            }
```

Comment: myLayer.removeChildren() just hangs the computer completely (on both google chrome and internet explorer 9). You can try it here - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/73176512/InteractiveGuide/index.html, just click the playbutton. (Just to let you know, my Javascript code is way too disorganized, I am sorry about that)

Comment: You want to remove the children from MainScreenLayer? Declare your layers outside the iniscene function so you can call them from within the playCorrectScene function. See if that works. Also don't log too much like that. Chrome can't handle that sometimes.

Comment: No that did not work either. I guess I will just have to set its visibility to false. Do you know if invisible objects are still rendered in KineticJS?

Comment: I updated my answer. Added the code in shape.js that says it will not draw.